# Greenplum database,postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, greenplum

How to find the list of temporary tables which have been utilizing in the functions in greenplum database

I am trying to find the list of functions only by using the below query

```
select pn.nspname as schema_name, proc.proname as fn_name, proc.prosrc as fn_body, proc.proacl as fn_permission
from pg_catalog.pg_proc proc
inner join pg_catalog.pg_namespace pn on(proc.pronamespace= pn.oid)
where lower(trim(proc.prosrc)) like'%create temporary table%'
```

but the above query returns function details only I need the list of temporary tables

Comment: I am afraid that won't be possible, but I don't know Greenplum.